# Converter Procedure em uma consulta LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

Estou tentando transformar esta Procedure em uma consulta linq no c#, consegui

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc]

@DATAINICIAL DATETIME,
@DATAFINAL DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT TB1.[RAZAOSOCIAL] AS CONVENIADA,
TB2.[PROCEDIMENTO] AS PROCEDIMENTO,
COUNT(TB3.IDCONVENIADA) AS NUMEROPROCEDIMENTOS,
SUM([TB4].VALOR) AS VALORTOTAL,
(SELECT TB5.NOME FROM TB5) AS NOMEEMPRESA,
(SELECT TB5.RAZAOSOCIAL FROM TB5) AS RAZAOSOCIALEMPRESA,
@DATAFINAL AS INICIO,
@DATAFINAL AS FIM
FROM TB3
INNER JOIN TB1 ON TB3.[IDCONVENIADA] = [dbo].[TB1].[IDCONVENIADA]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TB4] ON [TB3].[IDCONSULTAEXAME] = [dbo].[TB4].[IDCONSULTAEXAME]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TB2] ON [TB2].[IDPROCEDIMENTO] = [dbo].[TB4].[IDPROCEDIMENTO]
WHERE TB3.[DATABAIXA] BETWEEN @DATAINICIAL AND @DATAFINAL
GROUP BY TB1.[RAZAOSOCIAL], [TB2].[PROCEDIMENTO]
END
```

Estou trazendo uma lista de objetos, porém não estou conseguindo aplicar o Count, que tem ali na procedure para o Linq.

```
 var query = from tb3 in ctx.TB3
                        join tb1 in ctx.TB1 on tb3.IDCONVENIADA equals tb1.IDCONVENIADA
                        join tb4 in ctx.TB4 on tb3.IDCONSULTAEXAME equals tb4.IDCONSULTAEXAME
                        join tb2 in gtf.TB2 on tb4.IDPROCEDIMENTO equals tb2.IDPROCEDIMENTO


                        where tb3.DATABAIXA >= dtInicial && tb3.DATABAIXA <= dtFinal
                        select new
                        {
                            tb1.RAZAOSOCIAL,
                            tb2.PROCEDIMENTO,
                            tb3.IDCONVENIADA,
                            tb4.VALOR,
                            NOMEEMP = emp.NOME,
                            RAZAOSOCIALEMPRESA = emp.RAZAOSOCIAL,
                            DATAINICIAL = dtInicial,
                            DATAFINAL = dtFinal,
                            tb2.IDPROCEDIMENTO
                        };

            var dds = query.ToList();
                dados = query.Select(x => new DaoExemplo()
            {
                CONVENIADA = x.RAZAOSOCIAL,
                PROCEDIMENTO = x.PROCEDIMENTO,
                IDCONVENIADA = x.IDCONVENIADA.Value,
                VALOR = x.VALOR,
                NOMEEMPRESA = x.NOMEEMP,
                DATAINICIAL = x.DATAINICIAL,
                DATAFINAL = x.DATAFINAL,
                
            }).ToList();
        }
        return dados;
```

Eu tentei retornar a soma dos valores com o método Sum() e o total de registros conforme a procedure fazendo o uso de um select:

```
            var totalprocedimentos = dadosConveniadas.Select(x => x.IDCONVENIADA).Count();

            var valorTotal = dadosConveniadas.Select(x => x.VALOR).Sum();
```

O Valor me retorna os dados certo, mas o Count não está me retornando o total de registros da consulta e não pegando a quantidade pelo registro que preciso.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

provavelmente é assim:

```
var query = from tb3 in ctx.TB3
                        join tb1 in ctx.TB1 on tb3.IDCONVENIADA equals tb1.IDCONVENIADA
                        join tb4 in ctx.TB4 on tb3.IDCONSULTAEXAME equals tb4.IDCONSULTAEXAME
                        join tb2 in gtf.TB2 on tb4.IDPROCEDIMENTO equals tb2.IDPROCEDIMENTO


                        where tb3.DATABAIXA >= dtInicial && tb3.DATABAIXA <= dtFinal
                        group new {tb3, tb4} by new {tb1.RAZAOSOCIAL, tb2.PROCEDIMENTO} 
                        into g
                        select new
                        {
                            CONVENIADA = g.Key.RAZAOSOCIAL,
                            PROCEDIMENTO = g.Key.PROCEDIMENTO,
                            
                            NUMEROPROCEDIMENTOS = g.Select(x => x.tb3.IDCONVENIADA).Count(),
                            VALORTOTAL = x.Sum(x => x.tb4.VALOR),
                            
                            NOMEEMP = emp.NOME,
                            RAZAOSOCIALEMPRESA = emp.RAZAOSOCIAL,
                            DATAINICIAL = dtInicial,
                            DATAFINAL = dtFinal, 
                            
                        };
```

Answer (score -1):

Se dadosConveniadas é uma coleção, você já tentou;

```
dadosConveniadas.Count();
```

ou usando query sintax;

```
var QrCount = (from conveniada in dadosConveniadas                                                         
                         select conveniada).Count();
```